# Removing many-to-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, many-to-many, entity-framework-5

I have two classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Username {get;set;}

    [InverseProperty("Users")]
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags {get;set;}
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}

    [InverseProperty("Tags")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get;set;}
}
```

This clearly results in 3rd table that resembles many-to-many relationship called UserTags, that has only two columns, UserId and TagId.

Now assume I have 100.000 Users and 100.000 Tags, on average each Eser has relationship to 1.000 Tags. I want to remove a single Tag from the specific User.Tags collection without having to load all Tags prior to that.

What is the fastest way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Create dummy objects for existing user and tag
var user = new User { Id = existingUserId };
var tag = new Tag { Id = existingTagId };
user.Tags.Add(tag);

// Start tracking user and related tag as unchanged
dbContext.Users.Attach(user);
// Remove relation between user and tag
user.Tags.Remove(tag);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you Ladislav. I've actually built an entire "framework" based on stubbed entities because of the pretty much same reasons, i.e. deleting entity without loading it. However I'm wondering if EF5 has brought some new feature that does this out of the box without playing around with entity states...